# Error on startup android application (Titanium framework)

Tags: android, crash, titanium

I've a problem with my Titanium Android application. The app works correctly in iOS, but not in Android.

I get the following error:

```
V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [88,88] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.hasCameraPermission
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.hasStoragePermission
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 27: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 27: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.hasCameraPermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 27: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.requestCameraPermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 80: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fe92a0)
```

Can anybody help me help me?

Comment: Try formatting your question better next time and maybe you'll receive more help.

Comment: did you ever resolve this i have a simular issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229521/appcelerator-could-not-find-method-android-app-activity-checkselfpermission

Comment: Yes I resolve this.The problem was about theme Holo.Light.I changed theme to Theme.AppCompat and than it started working.Second problem is about permission installation in API 23.I set target SDK on 22 and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Sory for the previos unformatted message.I send a screenshot of log file.
[android crashed log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTxPn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue relates V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAge. Check the [link](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/183056/android-app-crashing-with-warn-messages-v8object-krollruntimethread-139139-runtime-disposed-cannot-set-property-userage)

Comment: Yes I tried this with installation of NDK and setting NDK PATH but the same error remain.