# Appcelerator Titanium 5.5.1 Android Geolocation Module Gives checkSelfPermission and requestPermissions Errors

Tags: android, geolocation, titanium, appcelerator, android-permissions

I am trying to invoke the geolocation module in what I think is a very simple way, but am running into errors. I'm testing on a physical phone, which is a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.4.2. Here's the code, which is being run from within the controller .js for my page:

```
function getGPSCoordinates() {
  if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
    Ti.Geolocation.purpose = 'Corollate photos with store location';
    Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
    Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
      if (e.error == true)
        console.error(e.error);
      else
        console.warn(e.coords);
    });
  }
}

if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled)
  getGPSCoordinates();
else {
  Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE, function(e) {
    getGPSCoordinates();
  });
}
```

...and here are the errors being returned in the log:

```
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.geolocation.GeolocationModule.hasLocationPermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 27: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.geolocation.GeolocationModule.requestLocationPermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 74: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

I did a clean build and the problems persist. I also looked at build/android/androidmanifest.xml and can see that the proper permissions are being automatically added to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

The relevant portions of my development environment are as follows:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 16.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.7
  Core Package                = 5.5.1

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.31

Titanium SDKs
  5.5.1.GA
    Version                   = 5.5.1
    Install Location          = /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA
    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, iphone
    git Hash                  = b18727f
    git Timestamp             = 09/27/16 05:38
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.36

Mac OS X
  Command Line Tools          = installed

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Installed                   = yes
  Memory Limit                = 2 GB

Java Development Kit
  Version                     = 1.8.0_102
  Java Home                   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
  ADB Executable              = /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
  SDK Path                    = /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  1) android-23
    Name                      = Android 6.0
    API Level                 = 23
    Revision                  = 3
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
    ABIs                      = x86
    Path                      = /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23

Android Add-Ons
  None

Connected Android Devices
SPH-L710
  ID                          = 8c1af53b
  State                       = device
  SDK Version                 = 4.4.2 (android-19)
  ABIs                        = armeabi-v7a, armeabi
```

Please let me know if there's anything I should be doing differently.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does you app have location permissions on the device? Check your settings and turn them on for the app and check out this (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-requestLocationPermissions) for how to make sure you have permissions before requesting a location.

Also, there is another thread that had a similar report that might give you some insight. ([Appcelerator Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229521/appcelerator-could-not-find-method-android-app-activity-checkselfpermission))

Comment: I am invoking the requestLocationPermissions() method if I detect that Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled = false.  I had seen the other thread that you mentioned earlier, but the screenshot he shows is manually going into settings and turning on GPS. I'm thinking that most people leave GPS off, and I want Appcelerator to prompt them to turn on again if necessary.

Comment: Do you get a request to allow the app to use the GPS when you run the code? I just tried your code quickly on my Nexus 6P running Android 7 and it worked without issue.

Comment: No, I never see that request, but that's what I want to happen.

It looks like there might be a bug in how this works related to the version of Android being used:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23135

Comment: I just used a friend's phone who is running Android 6, and my program worked fine, so this is definitely an Appcelerator bug specific to Android 4.